# Pin UICollectionViewCell to top of UICollectionView row

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

[image]

Is there any way to vertically align a cell within a row? My use case is pinning a cell to the top of the row. The cells I have in the row have variable height and right now the smaller ones end up in the center of the row while the larger one consumes the row height. I'd like the small ones to be pinned to the top so that they are flush to the top.

Here is an example of variable sized cells; however, these are pinned to the bottom whereas I want to pin mine to the top.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview

Comment: What kind of a layout object are you using? The layout has full control over the cells' positions.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I am using a UICollectionViewCell, is that what you meant by layout object? If not do you have a resource for layout objects?

Comment: @JoshCaswell my collection view is using a Flow layout.